# Create and Update an element of List within a For loop in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I would like to create a new element in a named list that is the output of operations with other elements of the same list.

Reproducible data:

```
# Build Params Matrix
LAL <- c(1:3)
LEL <- c(20191:20192)
LIL <- c(30,40)
LOL <- c(1:2)
params.matrix <- expand.grid(LAL, LEL, LIL, LOL)
colnames(params.matrix) <- c("LAL", "LEL", "LIL", "LOL")

PARAMS.COMBOS = list()
for (ii in 1:nrow(params.matrix)) {
  TMP.ROW <- params.matrix[ii,]
  PARAMS.COMBOS[[ii]] <- list(
    "LAL" = TMP.ROW$LAL,
    "LEL" = TMP.ROW$LEL,
    "LIL" = TMP.ROW$LIL,
    "LOL" = TMP.ROW$LOL
  )
}

for (ii in 1:length(PARAMS.COMBOS)){
  # .. do something else ##
  PARAMS[["LUL"]] <- PARAMS[["LAL"]] * PARAMS[["LIL"]]
}
```

`PARAMS[['LUL']]` is not kept on each sublist within `PARAMS.COMBOS`. It is created "on the fly" but not stored.

A solution would be to create a new list as:

```
new.PARAMS.COMBOS <- list()
    for (ii in 1:length(PARAMS.COMBOS)){
      ## .. do something else ##
      PARAMS[["LUL"]] <- PARAMS[["LAL"]] * PARAMS[["LIL"]]
      new.PARAMS.COMBOS[[ii]] <- PARAMS
    }
```

Is it possible to update the `PARAMS.COMBOS` so I do not need to create another list? I guess the only way to go is to update "manually" the original list (analogously to create a new list) like:

```
for (ii in 1:length(PARAMS.COMBOS)){
  PARAMS <- PARAMS.COMBOS[[ii]]

  ## .. do something else ##

  PARAMS[["LUL"]] <- PARAMS[["LAL"]] * PARAMS[["LIL"]]

  ## .. do something else ##

  PARAMS.COMBOS[[ii]] <- PARAMS
}
```

Would this be the best way to go? Is there any good practices for this case?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `PARAMS`?  Your code doesn't show it being created before you assign to a subset of it.

Comment: Sorry, I think I missed ```PARAMS <- PARAMS.COMBOS[[ii]]``` at the first line within the for loop (similar to the "manual" solution below)